# How to create a modern looking contribution page?

Tags: contribution-page, theme, display

I have just came across this webpage where they seem to using CiviCRM. But would have an idea how did they created the layout of this contribution pages? Wordpress drupal or something else? https://action.aclu.org/give/now
I like the layout of it and wondering if can be implemented on our site using drupal?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Civi Bartik Public Theme](https://github.com/CiviCooP/civi_bartik_public) for Drupal/CiviCrm.

The theme has some configuration as to change colors, logo etc...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to do this within CiviCRM as it stands. But someone else seems to have similar ideas and may be thinking of developing an extension to do this.  See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/user-interface/issues/8. By the way, I don't see any evidence to suggest that ACLU are using CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like it's a drupal page using webform, according to the page source.  But I don't see anything in the source referring to civicrm.

But, since it uses webform, you might be able to create something similar with the civicrm_webform module.

Answer (score 1):

This may take you part way towards what you are looking for https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/recurringbuttons/tree/master